# What is container in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, terminology

1. I was going through this article
   http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-ioc-1.html and here the term
   container is used. The diagram below shows container. What is
   container in this article? Is it a piece of `code` or the bean
   `config` file?
2. Can Spring IOC be used in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 30):

In this context, a container has the meaning of something that provides an infrastructrure needed by some components to live.

You can imagine it this way:

- Like the JVM is a container to run Java Programs,
- A servlet container (i.e. Tomcat) is the thing that runs servlets
- An EJB-Container is the environmet where EJB live (see this wikipedia [article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EJB-Container) (in german, but you can use your browser translator))

The same way Spring is the container where Spring Beans live.

Answer (score 20):

Container is used to describe any component that can contain other components inside itself.

As per the Spring documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)

> The BeanFactory interface is the central IoC container interface in Spring. Its
>       responsibilities include instantiating or sourcing application objects, configuring such 
>       objects, and assembling the dependencies between these objects.

IOC is the core principle which Spring uses for Separation of concern concept . No matter what you use - Spring MVC, Security , Core , DAO integrations , you will be using the IOC principle.

Comment: This documentation is very useful.. Cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 8):

Container is piece of code which reads bean config file and performs corresponding actions.

Yes IOC can be used with MVC. Here is an article about it. [spring mvc](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/)

Answer (score 5):

Let me explain what the spring container is ..suppose you have a java application with one class named Student and with one variable student name. here  we go

```
public class Student{
 private String name;
 public void setName(String name){
      this.name  = name;
 public void getName(){
      System.out.println("Your Name : " + name);}}
```

Now you want the name variable should get automatically initialized to iqbal when application runs and the student object  should be available inside the main class.

- write an xml configuration file where you will define this Student object.

```js
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "Student" class = "com.packagename.Student">
      <property name = "name" value = "iqbal"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Now inside the main class we have ApplicationContext

```js
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
      Studentobj = (Student) context.getBean("student");
      obj.getMessage();
   }
}
```

SO please note here ApplicationContext ,this will act as a container and will create and manage the Student class for your application.

Comment: what if it is a web application or Spring MVC program where we do not use ApplicationContext then how does a container get created?

Answer (score 3):

I like this definition:

**Spring IoC Container** The core of the Spring Application Framework is its Inversion of Control (IoC) Container. Its job is to instantiate, initialize, and wire up objects of the application, as well as provide lots of other features available in Spring throughout an object's lifetime. The objects that form the backbone of your application, and are managed by Spring Container, are called beans. They are ordinary Java objects— also known as POJOs— but they are instantiated, assembled by the Spring Container, and managed within it.

Caliskan, Mert, and Kenan Sevindik. Beginning Spring, John Wiley & Sons, Incorporated, 2015.

Short **Spring IoC Container** is box where Beans live.