# What is meant by container? Web Container, JSP Container or Spring Container?

Tags: java, containers

Please elaborate with a small example what do we mean by a container in Java. What is web container or JSP Containe or Servlet Container or Spring Container? If possible can I have a link where I can visualize these concepts.

Comment: A container is something that contains another thing. The 'another thing' depends on the context. What did your research tell you thus far and what is unclear about it?

Comment: Here is what you are looking for - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnabo.html. And this one is for Spring - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8708529/738746.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A web container, JSP container or servlet container refer to the same thing: **a server which takes your Java web application and executes it**.

An example would be [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Eclipse Jetty](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/). You create your app, start the server and pass your application to it. So the server will "contain" your application and executes it (therefore it's called a container). The server will handle things for you, such as listening on ports and incoming requests or routing.

A Spring container executes an application written with the [Spring framework](https://spring.io/).

Comment: please correct my understanding here. If I have a spring Mvc application which also has other servlets and JSPs. I have deployed this application on JBOSS. Then JBOSS is the container (jsp+servlet+sping).

Comment: Yes, then JBoss is the container. You could also call it an application container or application server.